# What is the significance of seed value in HCL OneTest Data while generating the test data?

Tags: seed, test-data

I am trying to use HCL OneTest Data to generate the test data for a defined schema. While generating test data, there is a field as Seed value, so can anyone help me to understand what is seed value?

Answer (score 1):

The seed value is the reference to generate the same set of test data values. For example, if you give 10 as a seed value and generate the test data, then a certain set of test data records will be generated. The same set of test data records will be generated every time when you give the seed value as 10.